# Eclipse, Maven, AndroidAnnotations: MainActivity_ is generated but not included in apk

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-annotations

I know that there are a few questions here on SO that are quite similar to mine but still none of the answers there could really help me.

The scenario is this: I am using Eclipse + ADT to develop an Android app. I recently moved to Maven for dependency and build management, to make it easier to include Spring for Android, Google Play Services, etc. At the moment building with Maven (from the command line) works but running the app with Eclipse does not work anymore.

When I:

- add a new dependency to pom.xml
- do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to make the new dependency available in Eclipse (that's the correct to do it, right?)

I get this error: "/foo/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it."

I tried several ways of making *this* error go away, but I all I get is other errors:
When I:

- go to Properties > Java Build Path (Source tab) > Add Folder... > check gen > OK > OK

this error is replaced by "The type BuildConfig is already defined".

So I:

- go to Properties > Java Build Path (Source tab) > select Foo/target/generated-sources/r >  Remove

Ok, no errors now, but when I try to run the app on my device, I get:

> "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bar.foo.MainActivity_" on path: /data/app/com.bar.foo-1.apk

Checking in bin/classes however, I find that `MainActivity_.class` is indeed generated - but somehow it is not included in the apk, I guess?

Note that the I can also see the classes from my source code, so the following, for example, works:

```
BrowseNodesActivity_.intent(this).start();
```

When I check Properties > Java Build Path (Order and Export tab) I see that the folder /.apt_generated is at the very bottom of the list. Is that a problem?

By the way, the error is exactly the same if I remove all the target folders generated by Maven from the build path so that the build path (Source tab) shows only src, gen and .apt_generated

Is there a way to get this approach - using Maven for dependency and build management but not using any Maven plugins *in Eclipse* - to work?

Anyway, I also tried the following approach as was suggested here:

https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=30

I installed Eclipse Maven support by:

- installing m2e from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
- installing the Eclipse Marketplace
- trying to follow this how-to from m2e-android (SO won't let me post another link)
- I go to Eclipse Marketplace
- type "android m2e"
- find something called "Android Configurator for M2E" (is this same as the "Android Connector"?) and install it
- right click the project > Configure > Convert to Maven project

Then I get an error in my pom.xml - "Plugin execution not covered by life cycle ... com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2"

So, all in all, using the Eclipse plugins for Maven didn't work either...

Is there ANY way to get all of the components in my setup to work together somehow: Eclipse, ADT, Maven, AndroidAnnotations (and optionally m2e and m2e-android)?

Comment: Have you tried using m2e-android for Eclipse: http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/

Comment: See the lower part of my question: I installed something called "Android Configurator for M2E" from Marketplace. Is this the plugin you mean or is there something different called Android Connector? And what exactly would I do to resolve the "Plugin execution not covered..." error. I read somewhere that clicking on the error in pom.xml should lead me to the installation of m2e-eclipse plugin. But (1) it does not and (2) it is already installed and the error is still here...

Comment: The Android connector and configurator are the same thing. Which version of the maven-android-plugin are you using? generation2 is an old Maven goal that is no longer supported by newer version of the maven-android-plugin?

Comment: In my pom.xml I have declared version 3.8.2 of the android-maven-plugin. I was basing my pom.xml on the one I found here: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-helloandroidexample.html but switched the version number. Which goal name would I have to use with the newer versions of the plugin? (Also, building with mvn from the command does work, though!)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the `m2e`, `m2e-apt` and `m2e-android` plugins for Eclipse. If you have *Plugin execution not covered by life cycle* errors, just apply the Quick fix for it. This error is shown because m2e-android cannot use AAR libraries, yet. Enable `m2e-apt` to configure JDT to use the AndroidAnnotations processor, you can read it [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Maven-Eclipse). If its done, right click on the project -> Maven -> Update Project. At this point your app should compile, but the generated classes may not included in the APK. To resolve that, modify your .classpath. The correct classpath is [here](https://gist.github.com/cwc/5224145) in the *workin_cp.xml* file.